# How to get data from unpaginated API in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have written a node.js script to fetch data from the API. The API is not paginated, I get the data and process them. Sometimes I get 20k - 100k bulk data, as I fetch them and process them in memory, it leads to memory issues in Heroku. Is there any way to get paginated results from the unpaginated API?

Code

Sample API URL - [https://rs.api.com/data/{id}](https://rs.api.com/data/%7Bid%7D)

```
requestData(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        url,
        json: true,
      };
      request(options)
        .then((response) => {
          resolve(response.body);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           reject(err)
        });
    }); 
  }
```

Results from API

```
{
    "version": "v1",
    "data": [....],
    "total": 347
}
```

Comment: If the API does not provide a limit/offset (pagination), no. If they only return everything, then you have to work with everything...

Comment: Is there any to handle the memory issue?

Comment: Depends on how you work with the request/response. In general, streams can be used to work around the memory limit (not sure if this suits here) Your quesiton need more details.

Comment: Can you give more information on streams? I get the bulk data in JSON format and dump them into Mongo DB